# Eliminar mas de 1 registro en tabla con pk compuesta

Tags: c#, vue.js

Hola estoy recienemente trabajando sobre un proyecto con c#, vue,js en quasar y necesito que en mi tabla milimetraje me permita eliminar mas de 1 registro a la vez, esta tabla cuenta con una pk compuesta de varios campos que son el codigo de mercado, de grupo, calibre, especie y temporada, no sé como lo podría hacer, mi código es el siguiente:

```
public bool DeleteEliminarMILIMETRAJES(MilimetrajesObject request)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = dbproyecto.openConnection();
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        SqlTransaction transaccion = conn.BeginTransaction();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Transaction = transaccion;

        try
        {
            string query = @"DELETE FROM dev_auto_milimetraje
                            WHERE cod_mercado = @cod_mercado 
                            and cod_grupo = @cod_grupo
                            and cod_calibre = @cod_calibre
                            and cod_especie = @cod_especie
                            and cod_temporada = @cod_temporada";

            cmd.CommandText = query;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cod_mercado", request.codMercado);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cod_grupo", request.codGrupo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cod_calibre", request.codCalibre);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cod_especie", request.codEspecie);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cod_temporada", request.codTemporada);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaccion.Commit();
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaccion.Rollback();
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Este es el código en el vue.js que utilizo para eliminar, sin embargo este solo elimina 1 registro y necesito que elimine mas de 1 a la vez:

```
eliminarGuardar(){
      
            if(this.proptabla.selected.length > 0){
                let object = {
                codMercado: this.proptabla.selected[0].codMercado,
                codGrupo: this.proptabla.selected[0].codGrupo,
                codCalibre: this.proptabla.selected[0].codCalibre,
                codEspecie: this.proptabla.selected[0].codEspecie,
                codTemporada: this.proptabla.selected[0].codTemporada, 
                codPeso: this.proptabla.selected[0].codPeso,                 
                }
                console.log("objeto", object)
                this.$q.loading.show()
                this.$store.dispatch('Milimetrajes/ELIMINARMILIMETRAJES_ACTION', {obj: object}).then(res => {
                    if (this.exceptionControl(res)) {
                        this.proptabla.selected = []
                        this.cargarTabla()
                        this.$q.notify({
                            message: 'Se ha eliminado el registro exitosamente', 
                            timeout: 3000,
                            color: 'positive',
                            position: 'bottom-left'
                        })
                    }
                    this.$q.loading.hide()
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.error('ERROR: ', err)
                })
            }else{
                this.$q.notify({
                    message: 'Debe seleccionar al menos un registro', 
                    timeout: 3000,
                    color: 'negative',
                    position: 'bottom-left'
                })
            }
        },
```

Comment: Este método funciona pero solo elimina 1 registro a la vez y necesito poder eliminar mas 1 de uno a la vez

Comment: puedes crear un método que reciba una coleción de ID's, y en base a eso, que utilice este método por iteración o algo similar

Comment: Pero si esa tabla usa una clave compuesta, siempre te va a devolver solo 1 resultado filtrando por *todas* las columnas que conforman la PK...

Comment: Si trabajas con un motor SQL, lo que dices en la pregunta no tiene sentido. De acuerdo al estándar SQL, una tabla puede tener ninguna o una llave primaria, pero no puede tener más de una llave primaria (PK es abreviatura de _Primary Key_: llave  primaria). Esta única llave primaria puede estar compuesta por varios campos, pero eso no significa que tenga varias llaves, y no sé si es lo que quieres decir realmente. También puede ser que tu tabla tenga, además de la llave primaria, algunos constraints `unique`. Si es así, esos constraints no son llaves primarias.

Comment: Si bien tienen uno de los atributos de la llave primaria (que los valores solo pueden existir una vez en la tabla) y cumplen algunas de sus funciones (que pueden ser referenciados en una llave foránea), no se llaman llaves primarias. Creo que es mejor que edites tu pregunta y mejores su redacción para que pueda entenderse cual es la situación en la que te encuentras.

Comment: no veo codigo javascripot en tu pregunta ni tampoo vue.js si colocas esas etiquetas es para llamar a gente que sepa de eso y no encontraran de eso, solo c# y sql. Luego si tenes varios Id que serian tu pk, probaste pasarle en el where con el  `in (1,2,3,4,5)`

Comment: Y cual es el problema? yo no veo ningun problema aca...

Comment: Que como mencioné ese método solo elimina 1 registro, pero lo que necesito es que me permita eliminar mas de 1 registro a la vez